# how to output velosity with ur_modern_driver

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing a project about robot-teleoperation now. By using ROS I have accomplished the position-control（even though there are time-delay between the master and slave）.I find that the position control is not flexible enough,so I want to control the robot with velosity-control .After reading the explaination about [link text](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver) ,I learned that maybe it's possible to control the jointspeed. After I

```
 roslauch ur_modern_driver ur_driver
```

and

```
 rostopic echo /ur_driver/jointspeed
```

There is no response anywhere,what's failure and what I should do to control the jointspeed?
Any help should be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263466/how-to-output-velosity-with-ur_modern_driver/) by [bobpop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30045/bobpop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/ur_driver/jointspeed` is not a publication, but a subscription.

You're supposed to *send* it joint velocities, they will not be *published* there.

---

Edit:

> Maybe there are some mistakes in my expression ,I use `rostopic echo` just want to see whether it has changed after publishing.I attempted to see its message details by using TAB key.I found that it is similar to /Follow_Joint_Trajectory.That make me confused,why I need to set joint position again

The fact that it uses a `JointTrajectory` msg doesn't mean that you have to set `position`. See [RosWrapper::speedInterface(..)](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/blob/fe9762e9d52b20bf6d1640bd8d046db27b0774d1/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp#L546-L558). It only uses the `velocity` field.

This is also described in the readme (emphasis mine):

> `joint_speed` : Takes messages of type `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory`. Parses the first JointTracetoryPoint and **sends the specified joint speeds and accelerations to the robot**.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bobpop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30045/bobpop/) on 2017-06-08**:
Eh,which topic or command I should use？If I use the `/ur_driver/FollowJointTrajectory`,that means I must set joint position,velosity… I learned that it's a position control and position perhaps is not the most important value in my consideration , what  I want to  just move in  a direction.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-08**:
I'm a bit confused by your comment. The topic is fine, `rostopic echo ..` just won't do anything with it as there are no message published *to* it. You have to publish messages to it.

**Comment by [bobpop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30045/bobpop/) on 2017-06-08**:
Maybe there are some mistakes in my expression ,I use `rostopic echo` just want to see whether it has changed after publishing.I attempted to see its message details by using TAB key.I found that it is similar to /Follow_Joint_Trajectory.That make me confused,why I need to set joint position again

**Comment by [bobpop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30045/bobpop/) on 2017-06-09**:
oh,I got it.Thanks,gvdhoorn.By the way,I should use `trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory`directly instead of `control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>::Goal` ,it's right?